# Adding curly brace to the right-hand side of the equation

Tags: vertical-alignment, brackets

I want to add brackets on one side of the equation and write something adjacent to it. But, I'm getting those words in the line below while I need those at one side of the equation. Can anyone help ?

```
$$w_t(t-1)=E_{t-1}P_t={}_{t-1}P_{t}^e=(1-\zeta )E(P_t|I_{t-1})+\zeta P_{t-1},0\leq \zeta \leq1$$
$$w_t(t-2)=E_{t-2}P_t={}_{t-2}P_{t}^e=(1-\zeta )E(P_t|I_{t-2})+\zeta P_{t-2},0\leq \zeta \leq 1$$
\raisebox{\depth}{$\Bigr\}\scriptstyle Difference in the information set in the 2 contracts $}
```

It's looking something like this, but I wanted the words and bracket to be at right side of both the equations.

I'm attaching for the same. 
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe `rcases`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{rcases}
\begin{array}{r@{}l}
w_t(t-1)&=E_{t-1}P_t={}_{t-1}P_{t}^e\\
&=(1-\zeta )E(P_t|I_{t-1})+\zeta P_{t-1},
\end{array}
&0\leq \zeta \leq1\\
\begin{array}{r@{}l}
w_t(t-2)&=E_{t-2}P_t={}_{t-2}P_{t}^e\\
&=(1-\zeta )E(P_t|I_{t-2})+\zeta P_{t-2},
\end{array}
& 0\leq \zeta \leq 1
\end{rcases}\begin{array}{l}
\text{Difference in the}\\
\text{information set in}\\
\text{the 2 contracts}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Upvote for suggesting "rcases"...(it is new for me too... :-)  )

Comment: If you used `tabular` instead of `array`, the `\text` “wrappers” wouldn’t be needed. :-)

Comment: Really new concept, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Some details of math typesetting are very important. For instance in

```
{}_{t-1}P_{t}^e
```

the “left subscript” would not descend as much as the “right subscript”. Some tricks are useful to achieve uniform appearance (mostly phantom superscripts).

Also the terms in the left-hand side should have lowered subscripts to match the others.

Spacing around `=` can be achieved with `aligned`, rather than `array`. The vertical bar should be `\mid` rather than `|`.

I use `rcases` wrapped around with a new environment that takes as arguments a clearance (optional, default 2em, meaning that at least half this clearance will appear at either side (useful if the left part is short, set it to a higher value) and the text that should appear to the right.

The text is typeset in a `varwidth` box with its maximum horizontal size determined by the width of the left part and the clearance.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\newsavebox{\casesdescbox}
\newlength{\casesdescclearance}
\newenvironment{casesdesc}[2][2em]
 {%
  \setlength{\casesdescclearance}{#1}%
  \newcommand{\casesdescdesc}{#2}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\casesdescbox}
  $\begin{rcases}
 }
 {%
  \end{rcases}\,$
  \end{lrbox}%
  \usebox{\casesdescbox}%
  \begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\displaywidth-\wd\casesdescbox-\casesdescclearance}
  \raggedright\casesdescdesc
  \end{varwidth}%
 }


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{casesdesc}{Difference in the information set in the two contracts}
\begin{aligned}[b]
w_t(t-1)&=E^{}_{t-1}P^{}_t={\vphantom{P}}^{}_{t-1}P_{t}^e\\
        &=(1-\zeta )E(P_t \mid I_{t-1})+\zeta P_{t-1},
\end{aligned}
& 0\leq \zeta \leq1 \\
\begin{aligned}[b]
w_t(t-2) &=E^{}_{t-2}P^{}_t={\vphantom{P}}^{}_{t-2}P_{t}^e\\
         &=(1-\zeta )E(P_t \mid I_{t-2})+\zeta P_{t-2},
\end{aligned}
& 0\leq \zeta \leq 1
\end{casesdesc}
\]

\[
\begin{casesdesc}[4em]{\small Difference in the information set in the two contracts}
\begin{aligned}[b]
w_t(t-1)&=E^{}_{t-1}P^{}_t={\vphantom{P}}^{}_{t-1}P_{t}^e\\
        &=(1-\zeta )E(P_t \mid I_{t-1})+\zeta P_{t-1},
\end{aligned}
& 0\leq \zeta \leq1 \\
\begin{aligned}[b]
w_t(t-2) &=E^{}_{t-2}P^{}_t={\vphantom{P}}^{}_{t-2}P_{t}^e\\
         &=(1-\zeta )E(P_t \mid I_{t-2})+\zeta P_{t-2},
\end{aligned}
& 0\leq \zeta \leq 1
\end{casesdesc}
\]

\end{document}
```

I show two example typesetting, one with smaller text size for the description and wider clearance.

The `showframe` package is used just to show the margins of the text block.

[image]